# How i can solve this issu i am getting null value in custom newsletter field in magento?

Tags: magento2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtpON.png this is my image .i am getting issu in custom newsletter field

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to save custom newsletter field data in database through plugin but i am getting null value

Comment: Please check added answer. It will surely work for you. I have checked practically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below event to save your custom field data.

> Step 1: Please create file events.xml in path Vendor/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before">
        <observer name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\newsletterSubscriberSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create file newsletterSubscriberSave.php under path
> Vendor/Module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class newsletterSubscriberSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();

        if(isset($params['subscriber_name'])) {
            $name = $params['subscriber_name'];
            $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

With the use of above code you can save custom field value. It will work for you.

**Cheers!**